# Activate Accessibility-Service when TTS language is different than system language

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-4.2-jelly-bean, accessibility

I am working on application for **Pre-kitKat** devices that uses accessibility-service.

This application do not use **TTS(Text To Speech) services** any way but whenever I try to activate my accessibility-service then I receive following dialogue asking me to do some extra steps.If I cancel this dialogue then my service does not activate.

[image: TTSWarning]

Is this possible to disable this dialogue or activate my app with out this dialogue.

Comment: Have you found a way to hide this dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I think "system TTS" doesn't support your system language. Go to `[Settings] > [Language and Input] > [Text-To-Speech option]`, then check your system TTS and available languages.